# Android:Saving Data to Firebase from runtime generated textfields

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a medicine app. In my app there are 3 default text fields where user can enter medicine name and click submit button to send data to Firebase.

But I have added a “add more medicine” button by which user can add more text fields at runtime to add more medicines name.

My question is that how do I store medicine name to firebase from those text fields which are generated at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have in your layout file an `EditText` that looks like this:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

To get the text from from the input, please use the following code:

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

To write this text into the Firebase database, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("medicine").push().child("medicineName").setValue(text);
```

Your database will look like this:

```
 Firebase-root
   |
   --- medicine
         |
         --- pushedId
               |
               --- medicineName: "Medicine Name"
```

Comment: you are right this is for a predefined edittext in the layout, but in my case edittext are generating at runtime. like when i press "add" button at runtime then it adds a edit text at runtime then user type data in edit text . so how do i store that edit text data to fire base.

Comment: You can get the text in the same way I showed you in my answer, once you create dynamically every `EditText`. You can add all those EditText to an array, iterate over the array and get the text, right?